# table frequencies with custom column

Tags: r

For example, I have a matrix:

```
a <- c(2,3,4,3,3,2,2)
table(a)
```

output:

```
2 3 4 
3 3 1
```

but the output i want is:

```
1 2 3 4 
0 3 3 1
```

so from the example, actually the value range is 1 to 4....
because of the random value, the list may doesnt contain one or more element from the range
**when the value range is 1 to 4, i want the table have 4 coloumns with the not exist value filled by zero (0)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert 'a' to 'factor' and specify the `levels` before doing the `table`

```
table(factor(a, levels=seq_len(max(a))))
#1 2 3 4 
#0 3 3 1
```

If you need a custom `level` that should be specified as well.  Using the example from the comments,

```
a<- c(2,3,3,3,2,2)
table(factor(a, levels=1:4))
#1 2 3 4 
#0 3 3 0
```

Comment: thanks, but how if `a<- c(2,3,3,3,2,2)` the range still 1 to 4, and the output i want is = value 1 is 0 and value 4 is 0

Comment: @SofiUmmuAbdillah  What's the expected based on the new vector.  If you need the levels to be from 1:4, you can specify the `table(factor(a, levels=1:4))`